# How come that I lose reputation score every week and I don't see in my account why?

Tags: support, reputation

I have not downvoted anything. I can not see in my account that someone else downvoted one of my answers. Though I drop from about 852 to 813 reputation. Why? This is not the first time.

Comment: It's the Jon Skeet Effect. Jon's rep has gotten so massive its gravitational field is distorting spacetime, and sucking in rep points from all other accounts. Think of it as a tax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most likely answer is that a question or answer which gained you reputation was deleted or migrated to another site, and then your reputation was recalculated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Shouldn't I see this in my profile then? Just like I see that an answer got upvoted or downvoted.

Comment: No, I don't believe these events end up being shown in the profile or history. It's as if the post never existed - IIRC.

Comment: and if it is migrated, is the reputation migrated to my other user account?

Comment: Not sure offhand. I think rep *isn't*, but badges are. I think it's on a blog post somewhere...

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer Jon.  Booooo! to SO for obfuscating this and frustrating those trying to learn from their mistake and improve in the future. Maybe this comment will get deleted too. :-(

Comment: @RichardBrightwell: With the recent changes, you should see a lot more detail. I'm not sure whether that requires some level of reputation, mind you.